# Where is config.txt in Arch ARM image?

Tags: pi-3, archlinux

I am working on a RPI 3. Operating system is Archarm.

I tried a [suggestion](http://elinux.org/RPiconfig) to add `arm_control=0x200` in /boot/config.txt for my RPI 3.
So, it was expected to run in Armv8 mode.
However, after rebooting RPI, the system stuck almost immediately in the "Rainbowscreen".

You can imagine that I was not able to access /boot/config.txt to strip out the ARMv8 mode line.

To fix the problem I tried to mount the sd card in my computer. However there is no config.txt on the first partition!

Any ideas to access /boot/config.txt apart from a complete renstall of the operating system?

Comment: I am assuming your computer is a windows box. Have you tried a live CD. However, usually the boot partition is a FAT partition which you can read from a PC, Linux and even Mac IIRC.

Comment: My pc has ArchLinux as OS, not windows. I tried as root `mount /dev/sdb1 /home/user/sd`. Only showing directories "grub" "lost+found", "memtest86+" and "syslinux" and initram images.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: there was another partition `/dev/sdb2` that contained /boot/config.txt.
So I was able to remove the `arm_control=0x200` line.

Flawless boot!

Solved!